# how to access an object in the scope from the HTML in angular

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs, view

Im trying to add an 'active' class to elements, if a value on an object is set to 'true'

```
routeId = $routeParams.id

$scope.navigation = {
 'home' : routeId == 'home' ? true : false
 'articles' : routeId == 'articles' ? true : false
 'videos' : routeId == 'videos' ? true : false
 'misc' : routeId == 'misc' ? true : false
}
```

and then use

```
<li ng-class="{ active: navigation.home }">
```

the object DOES change according to routeId,
yet there's no change in the VIEW.
I tried many variations but maybe Im confusing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your object to return functions:

```
$scope.navigation = {
 'home' : function() { return routeId == 'home' ? true : false }
}

<li ng-class="{ active: navigation.home() }">
```

Comment: Make sure to inject `$routeParams`  into your controller.

Comment: $routeParams is injected in the controller, so I now use $routeParams.id instead of setting a variable outside the object, like I did before